# Modify VSCode Jupyter Notebook appearance

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter

Is it possible to change the appearance of Jupyter Notebooks on VSCode, for them to look more like the browser version ?
In particular, I find the inter-cells space (1) way too big, and the check mark that indicates the execution (2) to also taking too much place.

[image: VSCode Notebook Screenshot]

I think that at the end in a page I cannot see enough code.

Is it possible to modify that ?